# Does a level 3 Swashbuckler gain Panache from killing a 1-HD creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

> *Killing Blow with a Light or One-Handed Piercing Melee Weapon*: When the swashbuckler reduces a creature to 0 or fewer hit points with a light or one-handed piercing melee weapon attack while in combat, she regains 1 panache point. Destroying an unattended object, reducing a helpless or unaware creature to 0 or fewer hit points, or reducing a creature that has fewer Hit Dice than half the swashbuckler’s character level to 0 or fewer hit points doesn’t restore any panache.

Does a level 3 Swashbuckler gain Panache from killing a 1-HD creature?  Obviously 1 is less than half of 3, but also you should "round down" in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 4):

### That swashbuckler regains panache for that enemy's defeat

Half of a level 3 [swashbuckler](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/)'s character level [rounds down](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Rounding) to 1. Because 1 Hit Die is effectively *equal* to half that swashbuckler's character level (rather than 1 Hit Die being *fewer than* that swashbuckler's character level), that swashbuckler does gain [panache](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/) for reducing a 1 Hit Die creature's hp to 0 or fewer.

Keep in mind that regaining panache this way is based on the creature's total *character* levels rather than exclusively on the creature's *swashbuckler* levels. A barbarian 10/swashbuckler 3, for example, would need to reduce to 0 hp a foe possessing at least 6 Hit Dice to regain panache this way and *not* just stab down to 0 hp a comparatively nonthreatening 1 Hit Die creature!